# I am looking a formula for complex combination

Tags: combinatorics

I have a number of variables each with a number of categories. I want to calculate the number of all possible combinations in order to make statistics on each of them. I am looking for a mathematical formula to do this (Note that some of my variables have up to 10 categories).:
Let's take the example of the variables `gender= Male/Female`, `Age= Adult/Minor` and `race= A/B`.
These are all possible combinations I could have.

```
1-Male/Adult/A
2-Male/Adult/B
3-Male/Minor/A
4-Male/Minor/B

5-Female/Adult/A
6-Female/Adult/B
7-Female/Minor/A
8-Female/Minor/B

9-Male/Adult
10-Male/Minor
11-Male/A
12-Male/B

13-Female/Adult
14-Female/Minor
15-Female/A
16-Female/B

17-Adult/A
18-Adult/B
19-Minor/A
20-Minor/B

21-Male
22-Female
23-Adult
24-Minor
25-A
26-B
27-The whole
```

I hope I haven't missed any combinations.

Answer (score 1):

All of your categories have $3$ options, e.g. Male/Female/empty. As you have $3$ categories, this makes $3^3 = 27$ total combinations. In general, just add one to each category (the empty option) and then you use to formula to pick one from each category, i.e. you multiply the number of options from each category.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, for simplicity, your only categories are sex (male, female) and age (adult, minor). Then the total number of possible combinations is $4$, since there are $2$ traits with $2$ values each.
In general, if you have $n$ categories with the $i$th category having $k_i$ values, the total number of combinations is
$$\prod_{i=1}^n k_i$$
Assuming none of the combinations are impossible, i.e, if marital status was included, you can't be both a minor and married. If these examples are present more work is needed.